# emacs align function parameters vertically

Tags: emacs, text-alignment

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
void foo( int one,
int const & two,
Bar three)
```

to

```
void foo( int          one,
          inst const & two,
          Bar          three)
```

Is this possible to do using the `align-regex` function (with our without prefix)?

More generally, what does the grouping in the regex signify (is it the part that's considered the 'column')? And what is the 'parentheses group to modify (justify if negative)'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> and, in particular, the linked <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `align-rules-list` <kbd>RET</kbd> which provides some of the best documentation for alignment.

The "group to modify" means the group in the pattern which will be shrunk or expanded when aligning. You almost always want this group to be purely whitespace, in order to avoid deleting actual content.

The GROUP argument -- interactively "Parentheses group to modify (justify if negative)" -- is the number of the group in question in the regexp, counting from 1.

The justification part is a bit trickier. If you provide a negative number, then the same group is used as if the number were positive, but the 'justify' behaviour of the `align-rules-list` variable is also triggered:

```
`justify'
It is possible with `regexp' and `group' to identify a
character group that contains more than just whitespace
characters.  By default, any non-whitespace characters in
that group will also be deleted while aligning the
alignment character.  However, if the `justify' attribute
is set to a non-nil value, only the initial whitespace
characters within that group will be deleted.  This has
the effect of right-justifying the characters that remain,
and can be used for outdenting or just plain old right-
justification.
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I was having issues with emacs regexs. Neither of my emacs versions (21.4 & 22.4) have documentation on align-rules-list. So if you have multiple parentheses groups, for the purpose of alignment only the one indicated by the 'group to modify' is relevant?

Comment: For `align-regexp` that's correct. Also, Emacs 21 and 22 are both very old. You may wish to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

IMO that's a case where the use of regexps grows being complex. A function which makes use of syntax-ppss is easier:

```
(defun my-arguments-indent()
  "When called from inside an arguments list, indent it. "
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((pps (syntax-ppss))
           (orig (point)) 
           indent)
      (while (and (nth 1 pps)(not (eobp)))
        (setq indent (save-excursion
                       (when (nth 1 pps)
                         (goto-char (nth 1 pps))
                         (forward-char 1)
                         (skip-chars-forward " \t")
                         (current-column))))
        (when (and (< orig (line-beginning-position)) indent)
          (beginning-of-line)
          (fixup-whitespace)
          (indent-to indent))
        (forward-line 1)
        (back-to-indentation)
        (setq pps (syntax-ppss))))))
```

Comment: True, this is a pretty tricky case for `align-regexp`. I'd probably use a custom `align-rules-list` rule instead (as that way you can specify multiple groups to align on, which simplifies things), but this approach looks interesting. I really need to remember that `syntax-ppss` exists. +1

Comment: @Andreas Röhler, could you explain please in more details how to use this function? I have put it in init.el, rerun emacs, select the function and press tabulation and see no effect.

Comment: @klm123 It was just an example demonstrating the algorithm when called with point at the second argument. Extended it, so it should work also from inside the first argument.

Comment: @Andreas Röhler, ok, probably I'm to far from this. But thank you.