# Vertical alignment of function parameters in emacs user coding style

Tags: emacs, coding-style, alignment

**Foreword** (you can skip it): In emacs init.el I set up my code format style like this:

```
(setq bws-c-style
      '((c-basic-offset                 . 2)
        (indent-tabs-mode               . nil) ; All indentation be made from spaces only 
        (c-tab-always-indent            . t)
        (c-offsets-alist                . (
                       (access-label . /)
                       (defun-block-intro . +)
                       (substatement-open . 0)
                       (inline-open . 0)
                       (arglist-cont .(c-lineup-arglist-operators 0))
                       (arglist-cont-nonempty . c-lineup-argcont)
                       (arglist-cont-nonempty . (c-lineup-arglist-operators c-lineup-arglist))
                       (arglist-close . (c-lineup-arglist-close-under-paren))
                       (comment-intro . +)
                       (case-label . +)
                                          )
        )
        (hs-special-modes-alist         . (

                       (c++-mode "#if" "#endif" "/[*/]" nil nil)
                       (c++-mode "{" "}" "/[*/]" nil nil)
                       )
        )
        (c-cleanup-list                 . (
                       scope-operator
                       empty-defun-braces
                       defun-close-semi
                       list-close-comma
                                           )
        )
       )
)

(defun lconfig-c-mode ()
  (progn 
         (c-add-style "My Coding Style" bws-c-style t)))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lconfig-c-mode)
```

With such a style, if I have to break function parameters into several lines I can easily align them using just <kbd>TAB</kbd>-key:

```
void foo( int one, const int& two,
          const double* const three, float& our )
```

Very convenient.

**Question**:
**Is it possible to set up my code format style, such that it would align rather each word separately then a whole line?** Like this:

```
void foo( int                 one,   const int& two,
          const double* const three, float&     four )
```

P.S. I saw some directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411045/emacs-align-function-parameters-vertically/16414181?noredirect=1#comment29512241_16414181), but can't understand them and not sure whether they can be used to set up a coding style.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that I've been using for myself for a while.
There's more than a bit of code, so I've put it in a
[gist](https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/7362506).

It does something close to what you ask. Here's the result.

```
void foo(int                 one,
         int                 two,
         const double* const three,
         float&              four)
```

Just to make sure that there's no other code interfering,
start to test this like so:

```
emacs -q -l calign.el test.cc
```

Write some code, <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
And now <kbd>3</kbd> will align the arguments.
It does so when the region is active, otherwise just 3 is inserted.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be changed to align with <kbd>TAB</kbd> only?

Comment: You can chain it, but then you lose the ability to
indent code without aligning.